# Editing DataGridViewLinkCell

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, datagridview

Is there anyway to allow a user to edit a DataGridViewLinkCell using the built in DataGridView functionality?

I have some link cells, and I handle a ContextMenuItem  click that does the following:

```
dataGridView->CurrentCell = rightClickedCell;
dataGridView->BeginEdit(false);
```

But it just gives the cell focus and doesn't put it in edit mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: One idea was to change the "EditMode" to 

DataGridViewEditMode::EditOnEnter

.... Did not work.

Comment: Since I haven't received any responses (or any views for that matter), I went ahead and implemented a workaround that popped up a form with a textbox attached to it and programmatically changed the value of the cell. It's not really the answer, but I can't figure anything else out.